# OpenGL for XMBC on Wheezy

Tags: kodi, raspbian-wheezy

I've just installed a fresh wheezy install and updated/upgraded it.  I'm now trying to setup XMBC on Pi.

I added the apt key and source for this

```
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org squeeze main non-free
```

Did another update then apt-get install xbmc.
That all worked fine, now after a reboot when I login and run 'xbmc' it loads the xbmc X window but comes up with an error along the lines of "XBMC requires a opengl'.

Any ideas what I need to install?

Comment: AFAIK It's not possible - only OpenGL ES is supported...

Comment: xbmc has to be compiled for OpenGL ES support.